# What is the minimum required file to generate a .yaml from a .nw in newchem?

Tags: q#

I am using nwchem (with powershell as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/libraries/chemistry/installation) to generate .yamls so that I can do resource estimation using q#.

I successfully converted a provided example .nw file into a yaml with this method, and I've included the .nw below

```
start n2_0_75Re_sto3g

echo

geometry units bohr
symmetry c1
  n 0 0   -0.7755
  n 0 0    0.7755
end

basis 
 * library sto-3g
end

scf
thresh 1.0e-10
tol2e 1.0e-10
singlet
rhf
end

tce
2eorb
2emet 13
tilesize 1
ccsd
thresh 1.0e-6
nroots 1
end

set tce:print_integrals T
set tce:qorb 10
set tce:qela  7
set tce:qelb  7

task tce energy

mcscf
  active  10
  actelec 14
  multiplicity 1
end

task mcscf
```

I'd like to better understand how to make my own for a different molecule. Using the code provided in the  nwchem tutorial - https://github.com/nwchemgit/nwchem/wiki/Getting-Started#simple-input-file----scf-geometry-optimization - where they provide the supposed minimal information to run something on nwchem:

```
title "Nitrogen cc-pvdz SCF geometry optimization"
 geometry  
   n 0 0 0
   n 0 0 1.08
 end
 basis
   n library cc-pvdz
 end
 task scf optimize
```

This seems to run through nwchem successfully but errors before generating the yaml:

```
File "/opt/nwchem/contrib/quasar/export_chem_library_yaml.py", line 298, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/nwchem/contrib/quasar/export_chem_library_yaml.py", line 291, in main
    emitter_yaml_func()
  File "/opt/nwchem/contrib/quasar/export_chem_library_yaml.py", line 283, in emitter_yaml_func
    data = extract_fields()
  File "/opt/nwchem/contrib/quasar/export_chem_library_yaml.py", line 142, in extract_fields
    if geometry is None:
```

I want to use http://www.cheminfo.org/Chemistry/Cheminformatics/FormatConverter/index.html to generate the geometry coordinates of a molecule, and have a bare bones .nw file which I can insert the geometry into. After playing around I often run into errors like the one above, which seems specific to the final stage of converting the output into a yaml.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Tensor Contraction Engine (TCE) component of NWChem needs to be configured to output Broombridge files (the `quasar` component of NWChem, documented at [`contrib/quasar/README.md`](https://github.com/nwchemgit/nwchem/tree/master/contrib/quasar) in the [NWChem repository](https://github.com/nwchemgit/nwchem/)).
Using the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/quantum/libraries/chemistry/samples/end-to-end:

```
set tce:print_integrals T
set tce:qorb 18
set tce:qela  9
set tce:qelb  9
```

Adding those instructions to your input deck should enable outputting Broombridge. For more details, see Listing 7 of [arXiv:1904.01131](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.01131v1.pdf).